# How can trim spaces in all inputs without adding methods or classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove blank spaces from the begining and ending of inputs in general without adding a class or id or event

I tried this [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/3buqa2hj/9/) but is using **onchange event**

```
<javascript>
  function trim(el) {
    el.value = el.value.
    replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, ""). // removes leading and trailing spaces
    replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " "). // replaces multiple spaces with one space 
    replace(/\n +/, "\n"); // Removes spaces after newlines
    return;
  }
</script>
<p>Search1: <input type="text" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
<p>Search2: <input type="text" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
<p>Search3: <input type="text" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
<p>Search4: <input type="text" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
<p>Search5: <input type="text" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
```

Somebody can help me about how to make all my inputs trim input values (CSS OR JAVASCRIPT) like this:

```
 <script>
   Here in this script will trim blank spaces starting or ending so don't need to add anything in the input
 </script> 
 <input type="text" />
```

I tried this but is not working

```
 $(.input).text().trim()
```

Please somebody can help me?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you want this to run? On pageload? On button click?

Comment: if you can both will be a good help.

Comment: BG101 did a good answer but i have several scripts and will make conflict also i have prototype and jquery-1.4.min that's why I want something simple and useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try `$.trim` on `change` input with type text:-

**jQuery**

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
        this.value = $.trim(this.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Search1: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search2: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search3: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search4: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search5: <input type="text"/></p>
```

**Vanilla**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'text') {
      inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
      };
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Search1: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search2: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search3: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search4: <input type="text"/></p>
<p>Search5: <input type="text"/></p>
```

Comment: Is this code the only way to resolve this? The problem is: I have several javascripts(prototype , jquery) and don't want to make conflict.

Comment: OMG excellent answer you save my life, that's what I wanted. Thank you so much +1 for your help, +1 vote, +1 thanks.

Comment: Thanks BenG a million. The only code that I found that works is your "Vanilla" code. I have not found any jquery codes anywhere that actually work. Thanks so much.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Just use String.prototype.trim(). There are examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the easiest way i found :), it uses jquery hope it helps, it uses your function
The input have to be only:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

This automatically change all inputs, or you can asign to a class

```
function trim_text(el) {
    el.value = el.value.
    replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, ""). // removes leading and trailing spaces
    replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " "). // replaces multiple spaces with one space
    replace(/\n +/, "\n"); // Removes spaces after newlines
    return;
}
$(function(){
  $("textarea").change(function() {
    trim_text(this);
  });

  $("input").change(function() {
    trim_text(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function trim(el) {
    var trimmedValue = el.val().trim();
    el.val(trimmedValue);
}
```

Your syntax for .trim() is wrong.
To trim a input's value you don't need any regex, just try to change this:

```
$(.input).text().trim();
```

to this:

```
$('input').val().trim();
```

input is not a class, so you don't have to put the dot before it. Then you have to include it inside '  '. The value of an input is given by val() method, not text().

This will only trim the input's value, you have to use this inside a function in order to make it works properly, as in the example above.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Mathletics can you be more specific please?

Comment: You have a (presumably) global function `trim` which is never called. Then you provide the example `$('input').val().trim();` which will use `String.prototype.trim` on the string value, but you're not doing anything with it. That will simply return the trimmed value, not update the value of the input.

Comment: I know it doesn't work if you don't call it anywhere. I edited my answer, hope is clear now what I meant. Thank you